# How to change url of tag in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have pages for each tag on my WP site. And the URL for them looks like ***mysite.com/tags/name***

So my question is there a way to change this URL for example simply to ***mysite.com/newname***?

I want to remove the word 'tags' and customize tag name a bit in URL. Is it possible?

Comment: _"I want to remove the word 'tags'"_ - then how would WP know, that `newname` is supposed to be a tag, and not the slug of a post ...?

Comment: https://taxopress.com/remove-category-tag-from-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-base-permalink/

It says tag_rewrite_rules depreciated but it still worked for me...